# How to normalise data for a multi-dimensional 2d array using min-max scaler

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I've been using the example [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-regression/index.html#0) for predicting the Miles Per Gallon of a car based off its Horsepower to help guide me in using this for my own project.

The input dimension for my project is 1 by 3.

For this, I have done:

```
const inputs = data.map(d => [d.valueOne, d.valueTwo, d.valueThree]);
const labels = data.map(d => d.valueFour);

const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputs);
const labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(labels);
```

So inputs will return an array of arrays that contain 3 input values.

The next step is to normalise each value in these arrays which is where I become lost. I'm not familiar with .sub and .div like it shows in the example [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-regression/index.html#4).

Also, how would one calculate the .min and .max of the three values from a list?

EDIT: According to the link given above, it states:

> You can normalize your data before turning it into tensors. We do it
>   afterwards because we can take advantage of **vectorization in**
>   **TensorFlow.js to do the min-max scaling operations without writing any**
>   **explicit for loops**.

Just to clarify, does this mean .min() and .max() calculates the minimum and maximum for me in the 2d array without me having to do it myself?

Answer (score 1):

The min-max formula is the following

```
(x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
```

This computation can be done by using the following given `t` the tensor of interest containing all the data

```
min = t.min(0)
max = t.max(0)
t.sub(min).div(max.sub(min)) // here is the normalized data
```